# Special characters not displaying correctly in a Javascript string

Tags: javascript

I have a function that assigns a string containing specials characters into a variable, then passes that variable to a DOM element via `innerHTML` property, but it prints strange characters. Let's say I code this...

```js
someText = "äêíøù";
document.getElementById("someElement").innerHTML = someText;
```

It prints the following text...

Ã¤ÃªÃ­Ã¸Ã¹

I know how to use the entity names to prevent this, but when I use them to pass the value through a Javascript method, they print literally.

Comment: Those characters are not special.

Comment: Save all files as UTF8 without BOM, set the charset to UTF8 and make sure everything that could possibly have a character encoding is set to UTF8

Comment: ^^^ [**proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/TYkwp/)

Comment: *"Save all files as UTF8 without BOM..."* There's no reason they have to not have a BOM.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Don't like the byte order mark much, and some editors still adds that crap. Generally there's an option to save as "without BOM", I was just implying to choose that one. My editor doesn't have issues like this, so it's been a long time since I've had to fiddle with that stuff

Comment: @adeneo: The problem with saving UTF8 without a BOM is that there is no way of telling, just looking at the file, that the file is in UTF8. It could be ISO-8859-1. Or Windows-1252. Or anything, really. With the BOM there, it's unambiguous. If you have tools that can't handle the BOM, it's time to upgrade the tools. :-) More: [Are there downsides to serving UTF-8 with a BOM?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57035/are-there-downsides-to-serving-utf-8-with-a-bom)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - My editor tells me what encoding the file has, problem solved !

Comment: @adeneo: It **can't**, except using metadata it has stored elsewhere. (If it bothers; VS.Net can't even be bothered.) As I said: There's no way of telling *just looking at the file* what encoding it's in.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - There's the file header, it usually has that information, even if there is no guarantee. Other than that my editor is probably guessing, but it does seem to get it right every darn time.

Comment: @adeneo: What "file header"? If you're using a Mac, it has the four-byte type code it stores in the directory entry. (I don't know if it uses it for *this*, I'm not a Mac guy.) But that's just the Mac. Other OS's have only the file data and name to work from. If you store without a BOM, and if the name is ambiguous ( ends with `.html`, for instance, which could be anything), then it's impossible to say with any certainty what the encoding/character set of the file is. There is no magical "header" anywhere. (Arguably, that's what the BOM is. The Unicode consortium call it a "signature.")

Comment: @adeneo: Re your editor: It probably just has a default setting. I wish VS.Net had a reasonable default setting. :-) GEdit on Ubuntu for my locale, for instance, defaults to UTF8 w/out BOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you have a conflict of encodings. Your JavaScript and your HTML are being served to the browser with different encodings/character sets. Ensure that they're encoded in and [served with](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset) the *same* encoding / character set (UTF8 is a [good choice](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings)) to make sure that characters are correctly interpreted.

Obligatory link: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)